# How to import xls file in to MySQL table

Tags: csv, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 operating system and I want to import excel sheet(.xls) in to database.

I am using phpmyadmin mysql administration tool. If any one can give me the commands to import xls to mysql I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Import CSV file in to MySQL Table**

Change file type in to CSV

Create table according to excel column names

Place the csv file in `/var/lib/mysql`

Open phpmyadmin sql command pane:
Execute this sql command

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'testlist.csv'
INTO TABLE TEST
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Use the load data capability. See
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

**Export CSV file in to MySQL Table**

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... 
INTO OUTFILE 'testlist.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

Here is an example that produces a file in the comma-separated values (CSV) format used by many programs:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM test_table;
```